# Configuration for connecting to subnet

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, openstack, openstack-neutron

I need to connect two virtual subnets. Hare is my topology on openstack: [Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh65n.jpg)

There are two routers attached to blue network. First is external router on 192.168.9.1 gateway and second is connected to red network with 192.168.9.9 gateway

I added additional routes for blue network: 192.168.10.0/24 > Next hop:192.168.9.9

When i try to ping red network instance from blue network instance I get:

```
[cloud-user@py-script ~]$ ping 192.168.10.9
PING 192.168.10.9 (192.168.10.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.9.9 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.9.9 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.9.9 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable

[cloud-user@py-script ~]$ ip route
default via 192.168.9.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 192.168.9.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp  metric 100 
192.168.9.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.9.5  metric 100 
192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.9.9 dev eth0  proto dhcp  metric 100
```

Did i missed something? On blue network will be app and on red network will be database.

Comment: Have you added the corresponding rules for the `192.168.9.0/24` network to the other side? Both ends must have the proper routes set up for this to work. If the routes are there and it still doesn't work, please show TCPDump on all machines (source, router(s) and destination) when you are pinging.

Comment: As mentioned above, you need routes on both sides so that the routers know not only how to get the traffic there, but to get back. You should edit your question to include the routes on each router, and the IP addresses each has on each interface. Then we could gladly point you in the right direction.